# Nhibernate: Multiple classmaps for one entityclass

Tags: c#, nhibernate

So, I'm writing a reusable library. And Nhibernate mapping by code is used for ORM operations. There will be multiple services making use of this library so I want the library to behave as dynamically as possible.

There will be multiple services and for every service there will be specific tables found in the database, these are prefixed by their service name. Unity will inject this prefix and that all works nice and dandy when using only one service.

But now I'm at the point where I have to write a service that will read and combine from multiple services. So this libdummy item will have to be mapped multiple times with different table prefixes.

```
public class LibDummy
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Guid { get; set; }
}

public class LibDummyMapping : ClassMapping<LibDummy>
{
    public LibDummyMapping(ServiceName service)
    {
        Table($"{service.Name}_LibDummy");

        Id(o => o.Id, m => m.Column("Id"));
        Property(o => o.Guid, m => m.Column("Guid"));
    }
}
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
public class FirstLibDummyMapping : LibDummyMapping
{
    public FirstLibDummyMapping (ServiceName service) : base(service)
    {
    }
}

public class SecondLibDummyMapping : LibDummyMapping
{
    public SecondLibDummyMapping (ServiceName service) : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

But this will throw a "Duplicate class/entity mapping" error.
And with 2 different classmaps for the same entity it will throw a Collection already mapped error.

Ideally I would have one dynamic classmap that can just be natively used in the library, but that's not an option i guess??

Any ideas for this, or is this something that is just not going to work?

Comment: nhibernate doesn't support dynamic mapping like that.

Answer (score 0):

Any NHibernate guru's with a definitive answer?